# C++ type of dereferenced iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I tried to make a function that sums all elements of an `std::vector`:

```
template<typename IteratorT>
auto sum(IteratorT first, IteratorT last) -> decltype(*first) {
    decltype(*first) sum = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        sum += *first;

    return sum;
}
```

and I got this error:

> cannot convert from 'int' to 'int&'

Then after some research I found this: `std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::difference_type`. Changed my code to:

```
template<typename IteratorT>
auto sum(IteratorT first, IteratorT last) -> typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::difference_type {
    std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::difference_type sum = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        sum += *first;

    return sum;
}
```

and it did work, but I am not sure why and if it's a good solution or not. In conclusion I have two questions:

1) Why `decltype(*first)` returns `int&` and not `int` as I expected
2) What exactly `typename` before `std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::difference_type` does and why `sum` function doesn't work if I remove it

Comment: I hope you're doing this as an exercise only, because we already have [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: Yes, I know. I am just trying to learn more about iterators.

Comment: In C++14, just remove `-> decltype(*first)`. In C++11, you either need to understand `decltype` better, or just use a real return type (namely `std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::value_type`). Also replace `decltype(*first) sum` with that type.

Comment: @KerrekSB So, there is no way to use `decltype` to get the type from an iterator. Right?

Comment: @DimChtz: There is, but it involves type traits such as `std::remove_reference` or `std::decay`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems:

- The type of a a dereferenced iterator is a reference, it can be `const`, and for a `std::vector` it can be very different from the vector's item type.
- When the item type is e.g. `bool`, you don't want to do the sum in `bool` type.

The following code is one solution:

```
#include <iterator>     // std::iterator_traits

template< class Iter >
auto sum( Iter first, Iter last )
    -> decltype( typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type() + 0 )
{
    decltype( typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type() + 0 ) sum = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        sum += *first;
    return sum;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

#define ITEMS( x ) begin( x ), end( x )

auto main()
    -> int
{
    vector<double> const v1 = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
    cout << sum( ITEMS(v1) ) << endl;

    vector<bool> const v2 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
    cout << sum( ITEMS( v2) ) << endl;
}
```

Note that you don't have to define your own `sum`: there is `std::accumulate`.

Comment: Thank you, and yes I am aware of `std::accumulate`. Just trying to learn.

Comment: Btw, what `+ 0` really does here: `typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type() + 0`?

Comment: It promotes the type up to at least `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`decltype(*first)` returns a reference, as else we would not be able to write things like

```
*first = 7;
```

Regarding `difference_type` it's not clear what you's trying to do. The word `typename` is required in order to tell the compiler that a so called dependent type (the usual case is any type after a `::`) is a template and not a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <
    typename Iter,
    typename Ret = typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<Iter>())>::type>
Ret f(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    Ret sum {};
    for (; first != last; ++first) { sum += *first; }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I need to ask is this: `std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<Iter>())>::type` better than this: `std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::value_type`

Comment: @DimChtz: What does "better" mean? They're two different things. Use the one that your design requires.

Comment: I tried your code and it works. But when I replaced `std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<Iter>())>::type` with `std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::value_type` it failed. That's why I asked

Comment: If it's not much to ask, can you explain me why?

Comment: Okay, it was just a typo. It works both ways. Thank you

Comment: I had expected that this would not compile for a `std::vector<bool>`, but it does. And giving the result 1 if there is at least one `true` item, which I think is an undesirable result. I don't understand how it compile for this case, but then, it's late evening for me.

Answer (score -1):

You did a random  thing, which works randomly. `distance_type` has nothing to do with your problem,  it's a type which denotes the result of measuring a distance between two iterators. Since more often than not it is a integer type, you ended up being able to use it in your arithmetic.

The original issue was due to the fact that dereferencing an iterator returns a (const) pointer to the underlying object - and this is needed so that code like

```
*it = 10;
```

would do what you want it to do (or failed to compile for const iterators).

And the `typename` keyword is required, but there are enough duplicates here on  `typename` usage here already.