# C++: how to use decltype to get type from iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Firstly, I have a `forward_list`:

```
forward_list<int> f {1, 0, 5, 4};
auto i = *(f.begin());
auto beg = f.begin();
```

Then I try to build a `vector` from `f`, and I would like to use `decltype` to get the type from iterator.

```
vector<decltype(*beg)> v{f.begin(), f.end()}; // compile error
```

But

```
vector<decltype(i)> v{f.begin(), f.end()};
```

works well.

The error information are mainly related to `memory`:

> error: 'pointer' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'int &'
>
> error: 'const_pointer' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'int &'

Comment: Dereferenced iterator type is a reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293409/compile-error-with-decltype-of-iterator-de-reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514449/c-type-of-dereferenced-iterator

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::iterator_traits` instead:

```
using type = std::iterator_traits<decltype(beg)>::value_type;
std::vector<type> v{f.begin(), f.end()};
```

or decay the dereferenced iterator type

```
using type = std::decay_t<decltype(*beg)>;
std::vector<type> v{f.begin(), f.end()};
```

Comment: using type = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(beg)>::value_type; `typename` is necessary here?

Comment: No, typename is needed whenever you use dependent types. here you don't have any. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293409/compile-error-with-decltype-of-iterator-de-reference) is an example of such case... it's working on a dependent type `Ptr`.

Comment: Should use `decay` instead of `remove_reference` for storage.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont 